# Point on a straight line specific distance away in C

Tags: c, 2d, euclidean-distance

How do I find the point on the straight line that is specific distance away from a given point. I am writing this code in C but I do not get the right answer..Could you anyone guide me on what I am doing wrong.

I get the x1,y1,x2,y2 values and the distance left fine. Using these I can find the slope m and the y-intercept also fine.
Now, I need to find the point on the straight line connecting these two points that is 10 units away from the point x1,y1. I seem to be going wrong here. here's the code that I wrote.

```
int x1 = node[n].currentCoordinates.xCoordinate;
int y1 = node[n].currentCoordinates.yCoordinate;
int x2 = node[n].destinationLocationCoordinates.xCoordinate;
int y2 = node[n].destinationLocationCoordinates.yCoordinate;

int distanceleft = (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1) + (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1);
distanceleft = sqrt(distanceleft);
printf("Distance left to cover is %d\n",distanceleft);
int m = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1); // slope.
int b = y1 - m * x1; //y-intercept


//find point on the line that is 10 units away from
//current coordinates on equation y = mx + b.
if(x2 > x1)
{
     printf("x2 is greater than x1\n");
     int tempx = 0;
     int tempy = 0;
     for(tempx = x1; tempx <= x2; tempx++)
     {
          tempy = y1 + (y2 - y1) * (tempx - x1)/(x2 - x1);
          printf("tempx = %d, tempy = %d\n",tempx,tempy);
          int distanceofthispoint = (tempy - y1) * (tempy - y1) + (tempx - x1) * (tempx - x1);
          distanceofthispoint = sqrt((int)distanceofthispoint);
          if(distanceofthispoint >= 10)
          {
               //found new points.
               node[n].currentCoordinates.xCoordinate = tempx;
               node[n].currentCoordinates.yCoordinate = tempy;
               node[n].TimeAtCurrentCoordinate = clock;
               printf("Found the point at the matching distance\n");
               break;
          }
     }
}
else
{
     printf("x2 is lesser than x1\n");
     int tempx = 0;
     int tempy = 0;
     for(tempx = x1; tempx >= x2; tempx--)
     {
          tempy = y1 + (y2 - y1) * (tempx - x1)/(x2 - x1);
          printf("tempx = %d, tempy = %d\n",tempx,tempy);
          int distanceofthispoint = (tempy - y1) * (tempy - y1) + (tempx - x1) * (tempx - x1);
          distanceofthispoint = sqrt((int)distanceofthispoint);
          if(distanceofthispoint >= 10)
          {
               //found new points.
               node[n].currentCoordinates.xCoordinate = tempx;
               node[n].currentCoordinates.yCoordinate = tempy;
               node[n].TimeAtCurrentCoordinate = clock;
               printf("Found the point at the matching distance\n");
               break;
          }
     }
}
printf("at time %f, (%d,%d) are the coordinates of node %d\n",clock,node[n].currentCoordinates.xCoordinate,node[n].currentCoordinates.yCoordinate,n);
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is how it is in math, I don't have time to write something in C.

You have a point `(x1,y1)` and another one `(x2,y2)`, when linked it gives you a segment.

Thus you have a directional vector `v=(xv, yv)` where `xv=x2-x1` and `yv=y2-y1`.

Now, you need to divide this vector by its norm, you get a new vector: *vector = v  / sqrt(xv<sup>2</sup> + yv<sup>2</sup>)*.

Now, you just have to add to your origin point the vector multiplied by the distance at which you want your point:

*Position = (x origin, y origin) + distance × vector*

I hope this helps!

Comment: Agree. I don't think you really need a loop here. This is algebra, not an algorithm, really.

Comment: Is that last `v` in the vector equation supposed to be under the sqrt or under the fraction or outside the fraction? You forgot to close the bracket :)

Comment: Oh OK, never mind. I understand. It is outside, you're just multiplying v with 1/.. instead of doing v/...

Answer (score 0):

Or simpler,

Find the angle from the slope

```
θ = arctan(y2-y1/x2-x1)
```

You might want to modify the quadrant of θ based on the numerator and denominator of the slope. Then you can find any point on the line at distance d from (x1, y1)

```
x_new = x1 + d×cos(θ)
y_new = y1 + d×sin(θ)
```

In this case, you have d=10